# Why should I use JWT tokens instead of api keys (Symfony)

Tags: api, symfony, jwt

I have implement a Guard Authentication 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html
with api keys.

Its fast and very simple. Others use in addition lexikJWT
https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-rest4

On my test system, lexikJWT is very slow. Do I really
need JWT? When I implement addUser, logout and expire
for guard I will have everything I need, or?

- In both cases, others cant modify the apiKey or 
  JWT token (then it is invalid) or produce new ones.
- If somebody stole apiKey or JWT token, he will
  have access in both cases.
- In both cases I have to store sensitive data
  (user, password, token etc.) somewhere in the 
  database
- With the apiKey there is also a role and
  a unique name/id in the database, so I dont need 
  this informations in a JWT token.

So where is the advantage?

Disadvantage in my option is

- lexikJWT is much slower, especially in a service 
  orientated achitecture with many different api calls...
- lexikJWT is third party software (how knows if 
  lexikJWT exist or is well supported in 4 years)

Thank you & Best Regards

Comment: JWTs are not as wonderful as the masses would like you to believe.  If you don't implement them carefully, there are attacks that are devastating (the "none" algorithm attack).  I would generally advise avoiding JWTs for session management.  See https://dzone.com/articles/stop-using-jwts-as-session-tokens

Comment: I don't think lexikJWT will be deprecated soon, it is officially endorsed by Symfony project.